# Sort array by frequency?

Tags: objective-c, sorting

What is the best way to sort an array of strings by frequency in objective c? Also, if there is a tie between frequency, I would like to sort by alphabetical order. And I want to remove duplicates.

I can think of ways to do this, just not sure what the most optimal way is.

["b","a","b","c","b"] -> ["b","a","c"]

Comment: Describe what you've thought of. Implement and worry about optimisation later if testing shows you need to...

Comment: I was thinking I could make a frequency dictionary with the strings as keys and their frequency as values. Then, step through the dictionary, pick out the highest frequency, add that to a new array, remove from dictionary, and repeat until the dictionary is empty.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is `NSOrderedSet`. That will enforce zero duplicates, and will maintain an order - this means that you could sort it and it will function similarly to `NSArray`.

Of course, you would need `NSMutableOrderedSet` to sort in-place. Here is a link to the docs.
https://developer.apple.com/library//ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSMutableOrderedSet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc(cs)NSMutableOrderedSet

Edit: All that would be required for you is to implement `- (void)sortUsingComparator:(NSComparator)cmptr` and give it a way to determine order.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed solution is ok, but rather than iterate the dictionary yourself you can use one of the built in sort methods and use the counts in the dictionary to decide on the sort result. If the counts of the two items your function is provided with match then you can apply your secondary sorting logic.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is my solution to solve this problem:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)sortByFreq : (NSArray *)inArray {

    //first calculate counts
    NSMutableDictionary *d = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    for (NSString *s in inArray) {
        if (![d objectForKey:s]) {
            [d setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:s];
        }else{
            [d setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[d objectForKey:s] intValue]+1] forKey:s];
        }
    }

    //create help array with keys to sort
    NSMutableDictionary *d2 = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    for (NSString *key in d) {
        [d2 setValue:key forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@", [d objectForKey:key], key]];
    }

    //sort keys
    NSArray *sortedArray = [[d2 allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator:
                            ^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2){
                                NSArray *a1 = [obj1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"];
                                NSArray *a2 = [obj2 componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"];

                                //compare
                                if ([[a1 objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:[a2 objectAtIndex:0]]) {
                                    return [[a1 objectAtIndex:1] compare:[a2 objectAtIndex:1]];
                                }
                                return [obj2 compare:obj1];
                            }];

    //create array to output
    NSMutableArray *outputArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSString *key in sortedArray) {
        [outputArray addObject:[d2 objectForKey:key]];
    }

    return outputArray;
}
```

i hope this help.

You can call it like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self sortByFreq:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"c", @"a", @"b", @"c", @"b", nil]]);
NSLog(@"%@", [self sortByFreq:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"c", @"c", @"c", @"a", @"b", nil]]);
NSLog(@"%@", [self sortByFreq:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"b", @"a", @"a", @"a", @"c", nil]]);
NSLog(@"%@", [self sortByFreq:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"c", @"c", @"b", @"b", @"a", nil]]);
```

output will be:

```
(b,c,a)

(c,a,b)

(a,b,c)

(b,c,a)
```